# " : cannot connect to X server " when trying to open image window

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, server, computer-vision

When I try to run my code on `AWS Linux` terminal, I get this error:

```
" : cannot connect to X server
```

My python code is

```
import cv2
import os

img = cv2.imread('white-transparent-leaf.jpg', 0)
print(img)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code perfectly run on my local Windows machine.
But whenever I try to run the same code on a Linux server, I get the error.

Comment: That’s because the server doesn’t have a screen attached. X is the UNIX and Linux standard for drawing on the screen. You need to configure your desktop as an X server and tunnel the X commands through your SSH connection back to your machine.

Comment: How can I configure this? Can you give me some suggestion how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Google lists many blog posts and similar that explain how to do this. For example: https://medium.com/@potatowagon/how-to-use-gui-apps-on-aws-linux-server-over-ssh-with-x11-forwarding-from-windows-1e80cd9571a8